# How to design a timer/timing pulley?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, gears, pulleys

I am asked to design a timing/timer pulley based on a timer belt which comes in standard size. How do I do the calculation to find the number of teeth, depth and width of groove etc?

Comment: Hi Binesh, welcome to Engineering SE. We aim to provide expert solutions to specific, focused problems. If there's one particular issue that's keeping you from being able to complete this design, you can [edit] your question to focus on that issue, and we may be able to give you high quality answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two aspects to this problem: mechanical (number of teeth) and geometric (width and depth of groove).
Solving the mechanical part  requires:

- $p$ the pitch (distance from the face of one tooth to the next) (probably mm)
- $v$ the speed of the belt (m/s)
- $f_i$ the required rotational speed of an element $i$ driven by the belt (Hz)
- $n_i$ the number of teeth on element $i$

This gives us the useful rule that, for any element $i$
$$2\pi r_i f_i = v$$
from which we deduce that
$$r_i = {v\over2\pi f_i}$$
and since $r_i = p n_i$, we can deduce that
$$n_i = {r_i\over p}={v\over2\pi p f_i}$$
so we already have the radius and number of teeth for each element $i$.

Solving the geometric part requires knowing the shape of the tooth (round, square, etc.), which depends entirely on the belt.